# Bulk insert in elasticsearch using elasticsearch-java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-java-api-client

I'm trying to bulk insert documents in elasticsearch using java with (elasticsearch-java).

I checked official documentation of elasticsearch-java and found information around bulk indexing in index, and i'm able to insert bulk data in index.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/indexing-bulk.html

```
List<Product> products = fetchProducts();

BulkRequest.Builder br = new BulkRequest.Builder();

for (Product product : products) {
    br.operations(op -> op           
        .index(idx -> idx            
            .index("products")       
            .id(product.getSku())
            .document(product)
        )
    );
}

BulkResponse result = esClient.bulk(br.build());

// Log errors, if any
if (result.errors()) {
    logger.error("Bulk had errors");
    for (BulkResponseItem item: result.items()) {
        if (item.error() != null) {
            logger.error(item.error().reason());
        }
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to insert data in datastream using this code i'm getting below error:
**only write ops with an op type of create are allowed in data-streams**

```
class Product
{
   String name;
   Map<String, Object> info;
}
```

How can we bulk insert data from java object.

Thanks in advance.

I tried below solution, but getting error while inserting in data stream

```
List<Product> products = fetchProducts();

BulkRequest.Builder br = new BulkRequest.Builder();

for (Product product : products) {
    br.operations(op -> op           
        .index(idx -> idx            
            .index("products")       
            .id(product.getSku())
            .document(product)
        )
    );
}

BulkResponse result = esClient.bulk(br.build());

// Log errors, if any
if (result.errors()) {
    logger.error("Bulk had errors");
    for (BulkResponseItem item: result.items()) {
        if (item.error() != null) {
            logger.error(item.error().reason());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try replacing *index* with *create* like this?

```
br.operations(op -> op           
        .create(c -> c            
            .index("products")       
            .id(product.getSku())
            .document(product)
        )
    );
```

Reading the [Bulk API doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.7/docs-bulk.html#docs-bulk-api-desc) about data streams, *index* does update existing documents if they exist, and it's probably why you can't use that. Using *create* should create new indexes, as expected of [data streams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/data-streams.html#backing-indices).